# How to get "RE:" reply thread in an email message

Tags: c#, mailkit

I am using the 'MailKit' to get the message from mail server.

http://solvedstack.com/questions/using-c-net-librarires-to-check-for-imap-messages-from-gmail-servers-closed

I have used the code which is under the text "I'd recommend looking at MailKit as it is probably the most robust mail library out there and it's Open Source (MIT).

One of the awesome things about MailKit is that all network APIs are cancelable (something I haven't seen available in any other IMAP library).

It's also the only library that I know of that supports threading of messages."

Now the problem with the above code is that I am not able to fetch the message reply. I have searched the message on the basis of message subject but I only got the first message not the other replies in the message. So can anyone let me know how to get reply thread in an email message.

Answer (score 3):

If your server supports the `THREAD` extension, you'll probably want to use that.

Here's how you might use it:

```
if (client.Capabilities.HasFlag (ImapCapabilities.Thread)) {
    var threads = client.Inbox.Thread (ThreadingAlgorithm.References, SearchQuery.All);

    // `threads' now holds the relationship of all messages in the Inbox
    // so that you can figure out which messages are replies to what
    // other message. Each MessageThread node will have a UniqueId that
    // you can use to get the message at that node and a list of
    // "children" (which are replies to that message).
}
```

If your IMAP server does not support the `THREAD` extension, you can do this instead to get the same result:

```
var messages = client.Inbox.Fetch (0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId |
    MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.References);
var threads = MessageThreader.Thread (ThreadingAlgorithm.References, messages);
```

If you are looking for the replies to a particular message, you'll need to know that message's UniqueId and then search through the `threads` structure to find the matching UniqueId. If that node has any `Children`, then those will be the replies.